# Node.js Mongodb save & create html

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, blogs

Hi I am trying to create HTML into my .ejs file. I saved the HTML line into MongoDB `"html":"<p>HelloWorld</p>"`

**MongoDB**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fbc146e93aea8f0bc7c904"), "date" : ISODate("2014-08-25T23:05:42.459Z"),  "firstname" : "ali", **"html" : "<p>Hello World</p>"**, "post1" : { "text" : "hello", "date" : ISODate("2014-08-26T15:09:29.338Z") } }
```

My Node.js application looks like this:

**Node.js App**

```
 var express = require('express');
    var port = 3000;
    var ejs = require('ejs');


    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID, 
     url = require('url');

    var db;
    //var mongo;


    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser());


    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //setup static public directory

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); //optional since express defaults to CWD/views
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // Start server
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('App started on port ' + port);


    // Initialize connection once
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", function(err, database) { //"mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
      if(err) throw err;

     db = database;

    });

    app.get('/user',function(req, res) {
        db.collection('user', function(err,  collection){
        collection.findOne({'_id':ObjectID("53fbc146e93aea8f0bc7c904")},function(err, user) {
        console.log(user.html);

        res.render('user.ejs', {test:user.html}); 


    });
    });
    });
```

In the following I am displaying the saved html but the problem is it appears not "HellowWorld" it appears `<p>HelloWorld</p>`  with the tags. How can I display it without the tags?

**User.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
**<p><%=test%></p>**
</body>
</html>
```